# Is it possible to see the number of currently running boost threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I'm working on a c++ project using boost::thread. There is a bug in my code somewhere, that sometimes starts new threads. I managed to fix it to some degree, but sometimes it still happens. Is there any magic way in boost to see the number of currently running thread? My aim is to do something like this:

```cpp
if(current_number_of_threads > intended_number_of_threads)
{
   do_something();
}
```

Btw I'm using visual studio code on ubuntu if it is relevant in any way.

Comment: Shared thread counter? Each thread increases it by one when it starts?

Comment: You can check threads using [debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) As well as with better [IDE](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks). unfortunately there is no way to detect whetter thread was created by boost or any another API like direct system call. 2. Strongly suggesting to replace boost::thread with std::thread - API is same but no dependency on boost_system.<dll|so> library as well as boost_thread which are generic and may conflict with your CRT/libstdc++